# Temperature of Closed Universe in future

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

This is a question from "Introduction to Modern Cosmology" by Andrew Liddle:

Suppose we live in a closed universe(k > 0), which will recollapse some time in the future. What will the temperature be when the universe has gone through its maximum size and then shrunk back to its present size?

Comment: I am pretty sure Liddle asks about temperature of *cosmic microwave background* rather than the temperature of the Universe as a whole.

Comment: To anwer your question, one needs to know the assuned value of the cosmological constant Omega_Lambda, a.k.a dark energy. If the constant is zero, then the average universe teperature will be aproximately the same for the universe both when expanding and contracting at a particular size. If the value is as positive as it it is calculated to be be now, then there will be no contraction.